# What variational problem does the parabolic suspension bridge solve?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

The catenary curve $y(x)$ minimizes the gravitational potential energy
$$\int \rho g y ds=\int \rho g y \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx,$$
subject to a fixed length, $L=\int \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx.$

It is known that in a suspension bridge the cable has a parabolic shape. This can be derived from forces. But what potential does that minimize?

Comment: crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/458331/11260